# Django1.7 'RemovedInDjango19Warning' when using apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, mod-wsgi

i am using Django version 1.7 for an application,
everything was running good in my developpement PC (i was runnin it using `manage.py runserver` command.

now i am trying to move it to a production server.
in the production server, everything is still good when running the server using the `manage.py`command.

but accessing the application remotely (via apache2 & mod_wsgi), i get an `RemovedInDjango19Warning` Exception.

after looking for a solution all i could find is how to ignore theses warnings for manage.py which don't work for me and i don't know how to disable this warnings from wsgi ?

**Traceback:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.0.17/

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_extensions',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework_nested',
 'django_gravatar',
 'authentication',
 'djcelery',
 'job',
 'seed',
 'proxies',
 'emails')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  98.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  343.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  372.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  366.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  109.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/var/www/cvc.ma/CapValue/urls.py" in <module>
  6.                        url(r'^api/v1/auth/', include('authentication.urls')),
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  28.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  109.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/var/www/cvc.ma/authentication/urls.py" in <module>
  2. from authentication.views import LoginView, LogoutView
File "/var/www/cvc.ma/authentication/views.py" in <module>
  4. from rest_framework import permissions, viewsets, status, views
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in <module>
  24. from rest_framework import views, generics, mixins
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in <module>
  11. from rest_framework.request import Request
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/request.py" in <module>
  20. from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/settings.py" in <module>
  22. from django.utils import importlib, six
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in <module>
  10.     RemovedInDjango19Warning, stacklevel=2)

Exception Type: RemovedInDjango19Warning at /
Exception Value: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
```

Comment: This traceback should simply be the result of running the app with the `-Wd` (display warnings) option, as described in the [release process docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/internals/release-process/). Why can't you ignore / suppress it?

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade rest framework? The code that was causing the warning [has been fixed](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/commit/daf1d59d0f41d2ea89e0b996d22b5d4e84914fb5).

Comment: you need at least 3.1.0

Comment: it worked, even though my code is broken now, 
is there any other way to solve this wihtout having to update the DRF ? at least temporarly?

if not edit your Answer with this so i could accept it.

Comment: The displayed exception may be caused by [`settings.TEMPLATE_DEBUG`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#template-debug) being set to `True`, and the warning exception raised during template rendering. Can you check if setting to False removes the exception?

Comment: i reinstalled DRF v3.0.0 and set  `settings.TEMPLATE_DEBUG` to False, still the same error,

i guess i should adapt my code to DRF v3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i ended up upgrading to Django1.9 and fixed the migration bugs.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because the `django.utils.importlib` module is removed in Django 1.9, in favor of the `importlib` in the standard library. Django Rest Framework still uses it.

You can disable the warning by following the instructions on the accepted answer of this question -- [How to suppress the deprecation warnings in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562070/how-to-suppress-the-deprecation-warnings-in-django)

Comment: yes i already used this approache, but it's not working for me,
may be the apache2 service is executing my application with -Wd option.
if it's true i don't know how to disable this

Comment: Did you restart the server after making the changes?

Comment: of course, even reboot the whole system when in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to silence the warning in `mod_wsgi`, you may add a configuration directive such as:

```
WSGIPythonWarnings ignore::DeprecationWarning::
```

See [this blog entry](http://arthurpemberton.com/2013/10/avoiding-deprecationwarning-messages-apache-logs), the [release notes (point 15)](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ChangesInVersion0300) and [the original issue](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/detail?id=137).

In essence, mod_wsgi had no equivalent to the `-W` control option, so a directive was added. The default must have been kept at "log everything" to be consistent across different wsgi apps.

Comment: i tried this, it's just ignoring theses warnings from showing up in the log fine,

i'm stil getting this:

[link](http://i.imgur.com/kBmMqro.png)