# Django 1.9 deprecation warning when using inclusion_tag

Tags: django, django-templates

When following code is invoked:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('template.html', takes_context=True)
def method(context, content_template):
    contents = template.loader.get_template(content_template)
    context['content'] = contents.render(context)
    return context
```

I get warning:

```
RemovedInDjango110Warning: render() must be called with a dict, not a RequestContext.
```

Warning disappers when second line of method is refactored to:

```
context['content'] = contents.render(context.flatten())
```

But I guess it is a walkaround, not a properly solution of this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix a Deprecation Warning in Django 1.9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002061/how-to-fix-a-deprecation-warning-in-django-1-9)

Comment: Mentioned questions don't ask about this particular issue. Here, Django itself provides a RequestContext, but the way to forward it to another template withotu triggering a warning is not clear.

Comment: The code itself makes no sense though. An inclusion tag is *already* rendering another template, in this case "template.html". Why would you, as the only code inside that tag, render a *third* template?

Comment: It's not the whole content of the function, but only the relevant part. It does make sense in bigger context.