# Silence a specific Warning in Django / Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, warnings

I want to silence a single warning in Django, when using Django Rest Framework with a default `PAGE_SIZE` setting, but no `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS` setting. I am in the exact situation presented by the error message as a case in which I can silence it:  I want a `PAGE_SIZE` setting globally whilst defining `pagination_class` on a per-view basis, case in which the warning says "you may silence this check."

But I haven't figured out how to silence only this warning without silencing other warnings (that'd be done via [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39899022/4038362)).

The warning itself is [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/checks.py) in the DRF source code.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#silenced-system-checks) in the Django docs, and, luckily, the warning had an id, so

```
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ['rest_framework.W001']
```

in `settings.py` did the trick.